# Ajax html document I18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internationalization, replace

I am using that code :

```
$.get(
    'filename.html',
    function(content)
    {
        $('#container').empty().append(content);
    }
);
```

to load some external files and place the content into the current working page. The external files that I load are in plain HTML and I like to ask, if there is any good way to internationalize that loaded pages.

In my current page I have the opportunity to create a javascript object with all translation keys like:

```
var i18n = {
    'doc1' : {
        'title' : 'This is a title'
    }
};
```

In example the external files looks like that

```
<h3>This is a title</h3>
.....
```

Is there a way to change that to something similar to

```
<h3>{doc1.title}</h3>
.....
```

and then after the load to replace the doc1.title;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this:

```
var i18n = {
    'doc1' : {
        'title' : 'This is a title'
    }
};

$.get(
    'filename.html',
    function(content)
    {
        for (var doc in i18n) {
            for (var key in i18n[doc]) {
                var val = i18n[doc][key];
                content = content.replace( '{' + doc + '.' + key + '}', val );
            }
        }
        $('#container').empty().append(content);
    }
);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kirrr/eW7Nn/

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this you're looking for:

**1. Updated**

JavaScript:

```
var i18n = { doc1: { title: 'Title', ... }, ... };
var doc_name = 'doc1';

$.get(doc_name + '.html', function(data) {
  for (var word in i18n[doc_name]) {
    data = data.replace(new RegExp('/' + word + '/', 'g'), i18n[doc_name][word]);
  }

  $('#container').html(data);
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3>{title}</h3>
```

2.

JavaScript:

```
var doc1 = { title: 'Title', ... };

$.get("doc1.php", doc1, function(data) {
  $('#container').html(data);
});
```

PHP:

```
<h3><?= $_GET['title'] ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your retrieved document contains

```
<h3 id="localTitle"></h3>
```

You could do

```
$.get(
    'filename.html',
    function(content)
    {
        $('#container').empty().append(content);
        $('#container #localTitle').html('This is a title');
    }
);
```